# if the records are identical, display other information into new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see second row data like start date, end date and associate into new columns in single row if they matching.

```
Name    Id  Start date  End date    Association
XYZ 100 1/1/2017    1/1/2022    Marketing
XYZ 100 5/1/2018    1/1/2028    Business
```

Result:

```
Name    Id  Start date  End date    Association Start date1 End date1   Association1
XYZ 100 1/1/2017    1/1/2022    Marketing   5/1/2018    1/1/2028
```

Business[image]

Comment: "...if the records are identical..." -- I assume you are comparing the `NAME` and `ID` columns, right?

Comment: What if more than two rows meet this condition?

Comment: Yes, we need to compare the name and Id. If more than two condition it should display them into new colums startdate2 enddate2 association2 etc

Comment: Is it a single table? What is the self join condition?

Comment: Yes, I have only one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is Solved:-

```
select Id,
  name,
  max(case when rn = 1 then StartDate end) StartDate,
  max(case when rn = 1 then EndDate end) EndDate,
  max(case when rn = 1 then Association end) Association,
  max(case when rn = 2 then StartDate end) StartDate1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then EndDate end) EndDate1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then Association end) Association1
from
(
  select id, name, StartDate, EndDate, Association,
    row_number() over(partition by Id order by name) rn
  from Business
) src
group by id, name;
```

[image: OutPut and Tested Code]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much Akhilesh.